# Captive portal (Wifi) remembers me even if I change my MAC address

Tags: wifi, macos, mac-address, captive-portal

On occasion I change my MAC address from time to time at a public Wifi service. However lately something has changed. The captive portal (Wifi) remembers me even if I change my MAC address on my Macintosh. How is that possible? Is it leaving a cookie on my computer somehow? If so, how to remove it?

Comment: Its probably next to impossible to answer this technical question without any details. In theory they could use cookies (or similar techniques), but its impossible to tell. Try a different browser and/or the private mode of yours. Also make sure your MAC is really changed (e.g. use packet sniffing software).

Comment: I only have one computer (Macbook Pro running the latest OS/X Sierra) so I can't sniff what's in the air. The Wifi portal is Starbucks coffee house.

Comment: Have you tried launching your browser in whatever its name for Private/Incognito mode is? Or even using a different profile than your standard one?

Comment: Every 'anon/4chan/foo' is using macchangers, Starbucks has probably found a more reliable method for tracking customers.

Answer (score 4):

It may use your WebGL ID (which never changes, unless you reinstall MacOS), or some other variable. Try disabling images, javascript (noscript, scriptsafe). Have a look at 
https://amiunique.org/faq . Disable flash and java as well via an appropriate add-on.

The obvious answer is that it's using a cookie, but I assume you've cleared those. Try clearing them pre-connect, and see what cookies are added post-login.

You will learn nothing useful (for solving your problem) by running tcpdump or wireshark. If you run it anyway, do a capture of 2-3 login sequences, and build filters later. I don't use wireshark, so can't help with those, but a tcpdump pcap filter may look like this (for capturing a HTTP captive portal session):
`sudo tcpdump -ni en1 -s 4096 host 192.168.1.2 and port 80`,
where en1 is your wireless interface and 192.168.1.2 is the IP of the captive portal.

Comment: Or employ a supercookie.